# Pandas Merging on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do conditional merging between pandas df:
My df's look like this:

```
df1
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'JJ', 'ABC', 'Tom', 'JJ', 'ABC', 'Tom', 'Tom'], 'Age':[10, 20, 25, 15, 25, 30, 30, 50]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(['Name'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
```

and

```
data_new = {'Name':['Tom', 'JJ', 'ABC', 'JJ', 'ABC'], 'Start_Age':[24, 18, 24, 25, 29], 'End_Age':[32, 22, 27, 25, 34]} 
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_new) 
df_2["Score"] = np.random.randint(1, 100, df_2.shape[0])
df_2.sort_values(['Name'], ascending = True, inplace = True)
```

I would like to merge df with df 2 to get score corresponding to the age present in df.
Below is how I am trying to do:

```
df_new_2 = pd.merge(df, df_2, how='left',  left_on = ["Name"], right_on = ["Name"])
df_new_2 = df_new_2[(df_new_2['Age']>=df_new_2['Start_Age'])& (df_new_2['Age']<=df_new_2['End_Age']) ]
df_final = df.merge(df_new_2, how = 'left', on=['Name', 'Age'])
df_final[['Name', 'Score']].ffill(axis = 0)
```

My expected output is:

```
Name    Age     Score
ABC     25       86
ABC     30       87
JJ      20       59
JJ      25       22
Tom     10       Nan
Tom     15       Nan
Tom     30       98
Tom     50       98
```

But, I am getting something else....where am I wrong??

Comment: So you mean, match age with start age if it matches, or end age if it does match too?

Comment: match age with age in between start and end age........and if no match found do forward fill using previous score for the same Name

Comment: Oh my bad, working on it to fix that part.

Comment: Shouldn't Tom with age 50 be null too?

Comment: no, age 50 is coming from forward fill from age 30

Answer (score 0):

Your ffill is incorrect. You need first to sort by name and age to make sure the order is correct and also group by name so only the score from the same person is considered. Otherwise the forward fill will take the previous score from any person:

```
df_final = df_final.sort_values(['Name', 'Age'])
df_final['Score'] = df_final.groupby('Name').ffill()['Score']
```

This is another solution to the problem. 
It uses a helper function to lookup the score.
The helper function is then used on each row to get the score for name and age.

```
def get_score(name, age):
    score = df_2.loc[(df_2.Name == name) & 
                     (df_2.Start_Age <= age) & 
                     (df_2.End_Age >= age)]['Score'].values
    return score[0] if len(score) >= 1 else np.NaN

# user helper function for each row
df['Score'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_score(x.Name, x.Age), axis=1)
```

You can still do the forward fill afterwards like this:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Age'])
df['Score'] = df.groupby('Name').ffill()['Score']
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution based on using `np.where()` to create the filters and then create a new dataframe with the output. Futhermore, I've changed the name of the column `Name` in `df_2` to avoid having columns with equal names. `df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_new).rename(columns={'Name':'Name_new'})`. Besides that, here is my code:

```
Age = df['Age'].values
e_age = df_2['End_Age'].values
s_age = df_2['Start_Age'].values

i, j = np.where((Age[:, None] >= s_age) & (Age[:, None] <= e_age))

final_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df.values[i], df_2.values[j]]),
    columns=df.columns.append(df_2.columns)
)
final_df = final_df[final_df['Name'] == final_df['Name_new']]
df_max = df.merge(final_df,how='left')
df_max['Score'] = df_max.groupby('Name').ffill()['Score']
df_max = df_max[['Name','Age','Score']]
```

Output:

```
  Name Age Score
0  ABC  25    41
1  ABC  30    46
2   JJ  20    39
3   JJ  25    96
4  Tom  10   NaN
5  Tom  15   NaN
6  Tom  30    78
7  Tom  50    78
```